# Trouble making a 5 x 6 wall of redstone lamps

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I am trying to make a 5 high by 6 wide cube of redstone lamps to work all at once but I'm having issues getting them to work. They need to be wired so that you can turn them on and off with a clock.

Here is what one corner looks like currently.

[image]

Here is the wiring I've tried so far.

[image]

Basically I'm clueless as to how I can wire the other wall and have all the lamps light up. The power is coming from underneath the center block.

Comment: I feel like I have the solution, let me try.

Comment: Are there lamps in the corner between the two walls?

Comment: @colorfusion nope

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### That's not possible with lamps in the corner

The problem, as I am sure you are aware, are the corner blocks. Take a look at a two high section:

[image: MWE variant 1]
[image: MWE variant 2]

To light up the corner blocks, we need to power an adjacent lamp *directly*, by pointing either a repeater/comparator, a line of redstone dust, or a torch (from below!) into it. Simply powering the adjacent lamps (such as by placing a redstone block/torch next to them) won't do. We can't do that directly on the corner blocks, meaning we have to power either both green or both red blocks directly.

However, none of the methods capable of directly powering a block fits in a 1 high space. Nor are there ways to directly power two blocks on top of each other at once, making a 5 by 6 full cube impossible.

---

#### Solution without corner blocks

However, if you leave out the corner blocks, it's definitely doable, although a bit of space below will probably be needed. The corners are still tricky, but you can use a torch/block/dust tower to light up most of it. The torch is connected to the input (green) underground.

Click on the images to enlarge them.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: This turned out to be a complicated wiring thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Powering corner blocks from the cube inside still remains an unsolvable issue, because no block around them can be directly powered, and neither the corner themselves, thus making the full cube impossible.

However, a similar solution can be achieved in this way: four wall of lamps powered from the inside

Here's the [world download](http://www.mediafire.com/download/fb1cvnbanf0hk37/6x4_Redstone_lamp_cube.zip). Some screenshots of it are shown below.

[image: outside]

[image: bottom internals]

[image: core internals]

Or either in THIS way. This is a 6 wide 5 tall lamp cube with no top level, except for the redstone layer, unfortunately necessary.

Second [world](http://www.mediafire.com/download/zscew7xeuqbd706/6x5_Full_Lampcube.zip).

[image]

These are the closest you can get to your initial idea, or at least, as close i could figure out :)

Comment: How did you solves the corner block problem?

Comment: I've edited your answer to improve the formatting, but if you're going to say you've debunked MrLemon's theory it's best if you back it up.

Comment: Sorry, i didn't mean to sound rude at all. Thank you Nitros for the edit if you thought it seemed like this. I think the best way is always show don't tell, so if you want, download the world and see how i managed, but I'll try to explain. The two upper layer were easy: redstone wire. The two lower, torches. The third was the tricky one, i had to figure out how to power the four of them symmetrically. Now, if you directly power a block, each block touching one of the five faces left will be powered too. I only had to figure out how to do symmetrically and it was done :)
Hope it's clearer now

Comment: This doesn't *really* debunk my theory. You only power the middle corner block from the inside, which is fairly easy. It's still impossible to do that for two blocks on top of each other. Still, your solution with the redstone wire and torches on top/below the wall do work if the roof and floor are allowed to come out by one block.

Comment: I suggest you [edit] the explanation into your answer. Comments are temporary.

Comment: Oh. 
I realized only now i did't make a "cube", instead a four wall lamp with top and bot faces as well. And also, with corner blocks you meant the six edges, the conjunction of three borders. Well, that indeed is impossible without a line of redstone on top...
I'll try some other puzzling to achieve a five faced figure, but yes, the full cube is by definition impossible.
I'll edit my answer with the improvements later on
Thank you @MrLemon!